# Best practices for moving objects to a separate thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, user-interface, singleton

We have an implementation for an Ultrasound machine application current where the Ultrasound object is created on the UI's thread. A Singleton implementation would have been good here, but regardless, isn't.

Recently, the set methods changed such that they automatically stop and restart the ultrasound machine, which can take between 10-100ms depending on the state of the machine. For most cases, this isn't too bad of a problem, however it's still causing the UI thread to block for 100ms. Additionally, these methods are not thread-safe and must be called on the same thread where the object was initialized.

This largest issue this is now causing is unresponsive buttons in the UI, especially sliders which may try to update variables many times as you slide the bar. As a result, sliders especially will stutter and update very slowly as it makes many set calls through databound propeties.

**What is a good way to create a thread specifically for the creation and work for this Ultrasound object, which will persist through the lifetime of the application?**

A current temporary workaround involves spawning a Timer, and invoking a parameter update once we have detected the slider hasn't moved for 200ms, however a Timer would then have to be implemented for every slider and seems like a very messy solution which solves unresponsive sliders, but still blocks the UI thread occasionally.

Comment: Are you allowed to use threads in medical equipment?  I thought the Therac-25 disaster outlawed that.

Comment: @Hans: Holy crap, I just looked that up on Wikipedia. That's about enough to scare me away from the medical software industry forever.

Comment: @Hans: I didn't see anything in Wikipedia that said multithreading was outlawed in medical software as a result of Therac-25. I'm perfectly willing to be wrong here, but it seems the real failure was not the race condition in the UI, but insufficient testing to find it, and lack of redundant safety mechanisms to prevent it causing damage (and what safety was there was ignored by operators). There shouldn't be an inherent problem with multithreading. Of course, when things happen, people tend to be irrational about placing blame.

Comment: If that was the case, I would assume Windows could not be used as an OS on medical equipment, since most of it is threaded, yet obviously it is used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing that's really great about programming the GUI is that you don't have to worry about multiple threads mucking things up for you (assuming you've got `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = true`, as you should). It's all single-threaded, operating by means of a message pump (queue) that processes incoming messages one-by-one.

Since you've indicated that you need to synchronize method calls that are not written to be thread-safe (totally understandable), there's no reason you can't implement your *own* message pump to deal with your Ultrasound object.

A naive, very simplistic version might look something like this (the [`BlockingCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx) class is great if you're on .NET 4.0 or have installed [Rx extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896.aspx); otherwise, you can just use a plain vanilla `Queue<T>` and do your own locking). ***Warning***: this is just a quick skeleton I've thrown together just now; I make no promises as to its robustness or even correctness.

```
class MessagePump<T>
{
    // In your case you would set this to your Ultrasound object.
    // You could just as easily design this class to be "object-agnostic";
    // but I think that coupling an instance to a specific object makes it clearer
    // what the purpose of the MessagePump<T> is.
    private T _obj;

    private BlockingCollection<Action<T>> _workItems;
    private Thread _thread;

    public MessagePump(T obj)
    {
        _obj = obj;

        // Note: the default underlying data store for a BlockingCollection<T>
        // is a FIFO ConcurrentQueue<T>, which is what we want.
        _workItems = new BlockingCollection<Action<T>>();

        _thread = new Thread(ProcessQueue);
        _thread.IsBackground = true;
        _thread.Start();
    }

    public void Submit(Action<T> workItem)
    {
        _workItems.Add(workItem);
    }

    private void ProcessQueue()
    {
        for (;;)
        {
            Action<T> workItem = _workItems.Take();
            try
            {
                workItem(_obj);
            }
            catch
            {
                // Put in some exception handling mechanism so that
                // this thread is always running. One idea would be to
                // raise an event containing the Exception object on a
                // threadpool thread. You definitely don't want to raise
                // the event from THIS thread, though, since then you
                // could hit ANOTHER exception, which would defeat the
                // purpose of this catch block.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then what would happen is: every time you want to interact with your Ultrasound object in some way, you do so through this message pump, by calling `Submit` and passing in some action that works with your Ultrasound object. The Ultrasound object then receives all messages sent to it synchronously (by which I mean, one at a time), while operating on its own non-GUI thread.

Comment: +1, I implemented this same approach for interaction with an unmanaged API that would actually check what thread you were calling it from and throw exceptions if you weren't on the same thread.  It's a bit awkward, but it works well.  I called mine `SingleThreadTaskRunner` and unfortunately implemented it before BlockingCollection and rolled my own synchronization with associated subtle race condition bugs.

Answer (score 3):

You should maintain a dedicated UltraSound thread, which creates the UltraSound object and then listens for callbacks from other threads.

You should maintain a thread-safe queue of delegates and have the UltraSound thread repeatedly execute and remove the first delegate in the queue.

This way, the UI thread can post actions to the queue, which will then be executed asynchronously by the UltraSound thread.

Comment: Looks like we had the same suggestion, but yours is way more concise. Also, probably more correct, as I did *not* double-check that code I included in mine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand the setup, but here is my attempt at a solution:

How about having the event handler for the slider check the last event time, and wait for 50ms before processing a user adjustment (only process the most recent value).

Then have a thread using a while loop and waiting on an AutoResetEvent trigger from the GUI.  It would then create the object and set it?